# Deadlocks in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, deadlock

Since upgrading from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 R2, several of our stored procedures in our nightly batch jobs that have been running for several year have started to die reporting deadlocks.

More recently I was able to reproduce such behavior with a simple select statement. What was interesting was the problem disappeared but adding a top 1000 to the select.

This leads me to believe that this may be a resource based issue and not a SQL issue.  Could it be the deadlock is not in the database but in a memory allocation process.

We did not have this in 2005, something must have changed, but I have no idea what. Are there any suggestions for getting around this issue , or is it a know bug or something?

regards

Julian

Comment: Can you enable deadlock capture trace flags (1204/1222) or run a profiler trace to capture deadlock events?

Comment: @mark  I will have some one look at this and see if can find something - thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Could it be the deadlock is not in the database but in a memory allocation process."

The answer to that is no. Locks are logical protection. Latches are physical protection.

Your query and a trace of the deadlock might help to research further.